# According to universalist Christians, is ill-will directed towards the devil virtuous?

Tags: satan, universalism, hate

Having heard of the arguments put forth by Origen regarding universal salvation to an extent that includes even the devil, I have recently been considering the inverse, that is, the possibility of the Enemy’s permanent damnation.

For theologies given to that premise, does it ever follow that hatred and contempt and ill-will, prohibited by Jesus when  directed at your neighbors/enemies may be a virtue when directed at spiritual enemies such as demons and/or of Satan himself?

Comment: an enemy is an enemy, at least IMO

Comment: I tagged this with _universalism_ I think that makes sense because after a second reading, my answer did not!

Comment: The question in the title asks the universalist position but the body of text appears to ask of the inverse position.  Could you please clarify; from whom do you seek an answer?

Answer (score 6):

Jude 1:8-10 says:

> Yet in like manner these people also, relying on their dreams, defile the flesh, reject authority, and blaspheme the glorious ones. *But when the archangel Michael, contending with the devil, was disputing about the body of Moses, he did not presume to pronounce a blasphemous judgment, but said, “The Lord rebuke you.*” But these people blaspheme all that they do not understand, and they are destroyed by all that they, like unreasoning animals, understand instinctively.

It is difficult, perhaps even impossible, for a person to harbor hatred, contempt, and ill-will towards another entity without an underlying basis of judgement.  Using the Scriptures as a guide and relying on the sensitivity of the Holy Spirit we are to judge between good and evil (particularly as we examine ourselves) and we are to hate evil and love good but we are never to pronounce judgement upon another entity.

The Scripture is clear:

> Vengeance is mine, and recompense, for the time when their foot shall slip; for the day of their calamity is at hand, and their doom comes swiftly. - Deut. 32:35

> Beloved, never avenge yourselves, but leave it to the wrath of God, for it is written, “Vengeance is mine, I will repay, says the Lord.” To the contrary, “if your enemy is hungry, feed him; if he is thirsty, give him something to drink; for by so doing you will heap burning coals on his head.” Do not be overcome by evil, but overcome evil with good. - Romans 12:19-21

The Lord God Almighty sees and remembers all and He reckons everything rightly without respect of person.  We may resist the devil, we should flee temptation, we should avoid people acting wickedly and work out our own salvation with fear and trembling but when we judge another entity we step into God's purview and this is what makes that sort of judgement blasphemous.

If Michael the Archangel is lauded in Scripture for refraining from such presumption we should stay well clear of it ourselves.

Comment: While I have trouble with the saying "Hate the sin; love the sinner," it contains at least some truth. Frankly, I believe Jesus does not hate Satan, but by the same token he hates what Satan stands for, and he hates what Satan does to hinder God's work on earth. While Christians are to bless and pray for their enemies, nowhere in Scripture are they enjoined to bless and pray for Satan that he might be saved. Martin Luther: "The Prince of Darkness grim, we tremble not for him; his rage we can endure, for lo, his doom is sure, One little word shall fell him."

Comment: I agree with Mike Borden from Catholic spiritual warfare perspective that an exorcist is NOT suppose to personally rebuke or insult the devil, but should declare the Lord's judgment against it (just as archangel Michael did in Jude 1:9), which in turn will cause devil the anguish.  We can command and declare the Lord's judgment but not throw hate and abuse against the devil.  If we do the latter, it will backfire since the authority is in Jesus's name not in the exorcist's name.  I also agree with @rhetorician that the Scriptures is silent about blessing devil, so we shouldn't do it.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple In the biography of St. Miriam of Jesus Crucified, she could not curse anyone. She herself was possessed by the Devil on at least two separate occasions. During one of those occasions she called on God’s blessings on the Devil. The howl that he made at such words  made everyone shake! St. Teresa of Avila said that we should always respect the Devil. Even as a fallen angel of God, his powers are impressive and we should not tempt him!!!

Comment: @KenGraham Thank you for providing the anecdotes, which are consistent with my understanding as well.

Comment: @rhetorician I agree.  In fact, we already know that Satan will ultimately end up in the lake of fire.  To pray for something different is to pray against God's revelation.  I believe we have that revelation, not to boast against the devil but to add resolve to our faith when the way gets rough.  "For Lo, his doom is sure"

Comment: @MikeBorden: Amen to that, brother! Don

Comment: Could you please add some supportive evidence that your answer is in fact that which is held by [universalist Christians](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universalist_Church_of_America)?

Comment: @KenGraham The question in the title asks of Universalists and the question in the body of text asks of the inverse position.  The Universalism tag was added by a moderator and not the OP.

Comment: @MikeBorden that’s right, the headline has been changed in a way that misrepresents my question :/